# Can I somehow combine these two web-page controls?

Tags: html, user-interface, controls

There are tons of things wrong with this page, but I'm looking for some ideas about how (if it's possible) to combine two controls on the page before I go any further.

The page presents a stream of real-time stock-market data. The page is at:

http://www.sellmycalls.com/cgi-bin/chain

(works on the PC under ff 3.6.13, safari 5.0.3, chrome 9.0.597; fails in IE 6, untested in IE 7,8,9)

The two controls I'm asking about are at the top: one on the "refresh" button; and the other on the adjacent combo box.

The user can refresh the data manually any time by pressing that "refresh" button. And the user can set up auto-refresh by selecting an interval from the combo box.

The separate button and combo box take a lot of room, though. And the two separate but related controls seem kind of clunky to me.

Is there some nice, obvious, intuitive, satisfying way I can combine the two while at the same time allowing the user to:

1. use the single combined control to do a manual refresh any old time, over-riding auto-refresh;
2. use the single combined control to set up auto-refresh;
3. see from the single combined control whether or not auto-refresh is in effect; and
4. quickly and easily suspend auto-refresh, thus freezing the display.

Any ideas very welcome and attribution will be given, natch.

Thanks so much!

-- pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most intuitive solution, but perhaps a combobox with the top item being labeled as Refresh, and if that is selected, it does a manual refresh.